# Access all tetrahedrons incident on a vertex

Tags: triangulation, cgal

I would like to know that how can we access all tetrahedrons incident on a vertex in a CGAL 3D triangulation?

I have seen [`cell()`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/TDS_3/classTriangulationDataStructure__3_1_1Vertex.html#a486641ee3eca55e5f32afcda7c7832c7) function for vertex, but it seems to allow access to one(arbitrarily selected?) tetrahedron only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had trouble using the `incident_cells()` function as I was not sure how to use the *OutputIterators*. [This CGAL forum discussion](http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/OutputIterator-td950197.html) *exactly* answers my question(with a [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23387778/985166)).

Answer (score 4):

The answer you are looking for should be [`TDS::incident_cells`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/TDS_3/classTriangulationDataStructure__3.html#ac1d372298c8949a754b4453ccffe2c1c).

Comment: Although the **incident_cells** function exactly satisfies my requirement, I am facing some troubles using it. Can you give an example code for explaining how to use this function. Further, I want to know Why it returns **outputiterator** both as return value and in argument under the name **cells**?

Comment: Specifically, if I want to access all cells returned by **incident_cells** function say in a **while loop**, what _termination criteria_ should by used(as it seems I only have access to iterator but not its corresponding container, so how to get access to _begin()_ and _end()_).